# How would you check to see it game piece is in given range to attack?

Tags: c++, logic

I'm writing a game that has pieces attack one another and for ex.

a tank has a range of 20 and is at position (1,1), how do i test what pieces would be in range. If the piece is out of range i can't attack it. The pieces are all placed within a two dimensional array

```
//these values are all passed in from a function
int x;
int y;
int targetX;
int targetY;
int range=20;

if (range+x < targetY-targetX)// i honestly don't know and can't figure out the logic
```

EDIT: I was trying to find distance on a game board like checkers, i.e but for the purpose of this program, radial distance makes more sense. Thank you for the help

Comment: Take out a blank piece of paper and a pen. Write down, in simple logical sentences, your proposed algorithm. Then, [discuss your entire algorithm with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck agrees that your proposed logic will work, simply take what you've written down, and translate it directly into C++ code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: my rubber duck agrees but not my code output...

Comment: Talk to your rubber duck, that's what he's for.

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer?

Comment: No, but im too low level to upvote any questions

Answer (score 0):

Is the range is radial? Meaning, can a tank shoot 360°?
If so, all you need to do is figuring out if the distance to the target is smaller than 20 (or small-equal, depends on what you want).

To calc the distance use the [distance formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php): sqrt((x-targetX)^2+(y-targetY)^2).

Comment: yes it is radial but distance are only ints and its on a game board like checkers

Comment: Ok, so round the result from the distance formula down to the nearest int (i.e. casting).

Comment: for instance if piece is on the game board at [1,1] and target is at [8,7] then it would take 7 spaces total to get to that piece, but the distance formula would give me a rounded answer of 10

Comment: And 10 is smaller than 20, so the piece is in range (if the range is still 20).

Comment: Yeah but if i could potentially not attack pieces that ARE in range because the distance formula will give me a greater number. I appreciate the help but i need a precise answer

Comment: I don't understand your problem - if the target's distance is larger than range than you cannot attack it.

Comment: > if piece is on the game board at [1,1] and target is at [8,7] then it would take 7 spaces total to get to that piece< implies you are taking the maximum difference in x or y directions - if this is so then say so in your question, otherwise people will assume that distance has the conventional meaning

Answer (score 0):

Just use the formula for euclidean distance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

inline bool in_range(const int x, const int y, const int targetX, const int targetY, const int range )
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow((x-targetX),2)+ std::pow((y-targetY),2)) < range;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << in_range(0,0,21,0,20) << std::endl;
   std::cout << in_range(0,0,19,0,20) << std::endl;

   std::cout << in_range(0,0,0,21,20) << std::endl;
   std::cout << in_range(0,0,0,19,20) << std::endl;
}
```